# How do I convert my resource id for image view to ImageView object in android app widgets.

Tags: android, imageview, android-appwidget

I am trying to display image from changing url in my code to image view. How can I convert my resource id for image view in layout to ImageView object. there is no findViewById in app widgets and RemoteViews has setImageViewResource but it accepts drawables only and not the id's in layout xml. Guys, please please help..

```
ImageView logoView = new ImageView();
logoView.setImageResource(R.id.merchant_image);//this is error as this id is not in drawable but in layout.
```

Please please guide..

Answer (score 0):

**Change**

```
ImageView logoView = new ImageView();
```

to

```
ImageView logoView = (ImageView)getView()findViewById(R.id.merchant_image);
```

**Edit** :

for your warning “Class loader may fail for processes that host multiple applications”

**try**

[Android: "Class loader may fail for processes that host multiple applications"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407006/android-class-loader-may-fail-for-processes-that-host-multiple-applications)

Comment: We cannot use findViewById in app widgets.

Comment: Also, I am not updating my resource id with drawable image but by url.

Comment: yes you can update that by url ! first get image from your url and store it to bitmap and than use : logoView.setImageBitmap(yourBitmapImageObject);

Comment: @Atihska sorry i got you point now, its little late ! try my updated answer !

Comment: 07-12 12:02:12.708: W/ActivityThread(5316): ClassLoader.getResources: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());