# Issue with using ormlite with simplexml

Tags: android, classloader, ormlite, simple-framework

I am currently using ormlite and simplexml. When I tried to convert an xml file to an object that has a ORMLite LazyForeignCollection object using simple xml I get the follwing exception. Can someone please explain how I need to handle this. Please let me know if you need any other information. I have had no issues with ormlite previously.

```
09-16 19:00:22.688: W/System.err(32274): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.j256.ormlite.dao.LazyForeignCollection" on path: .
09-16 19:00:22.688: W/System.err(32274):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
09-16 19:00:22.688: W/System.err(32274):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
09-16 19:00:22.688: W/System.err(32274):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
09-16 19:00:22.688: W/System.err(3227d4):   at android.app.LoadedApk$WarningContextClassLoader.loadClass(LoadedApk.java:431)
09-16 19:00:22.688: W/System.err(32274):    at org.simpleframework.xml.strategy.Loader.load(Loader.java:50)
09-16 19:00:22.688: W/System.err(32274):    at org.simpleframework.xml.strategy.TreeStrategy.readValue(TreeStrategy.java:163)
09-16 19:00:22.688: W/ActivityThread(32274): ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
09-16 19:00:22.698: W/System.err(32274):    at org.simpleframework.xml.strategy.TreeStrategy.read(TreeStrategy.java:102)
09-16 19:00:22.698: W/System.err(32274):    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Source.getOverride(Source.java:360)
09-16 19:00:22.698: W/System.err(32274):    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Factory.getConversion(Factory.java:207)
09-16 19:00:22.698: W/System.err(32274):    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Factory.getOverride(Factory.java:139)
09-16 19:00:22.698: W/System.err(32274):    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.CollectionFactory.getInstance(CollectionFactory.java:87)
09-16 19:00:22.698: W/System.err(32274):    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeList.read(CompositeList.java:116)
09-16 19:00:22.698: W/System.err(32274):    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readVariable(Composite.java:623)
09-16 19:00:22.698: W/System.err(32274):    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readInstance(Composite.java:573)
09-16 19:00:22.698: W/System.err(32274):    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readUnion(Composite.java:549)
09-16 19:00:22.708: W/System.err(32274):    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElement(Composite.java:532)
09-16 19:00:22.708: W/System.err(32274):    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElements(Composite.java:445)
09-16 19:00:22.708: W/System.err(32274):    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.access$400(Composite.java:59)
09-16 19:00:22.708: W/System.err(32274):    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite$Builder.read(Composite.java:1383)
09-16 19:00:22.708: W/System.err(32274):    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:201)
09-16 19:00:22.708: W/System.err(32274):    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:148)
09-16 19:00:22.708: W/System.err(32274):    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.read(Traverser.java:92)
09-16 19:00:22.708: W/System.err(32274):    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:625)
09-16 19:00:22.708: W/System.err(32274):    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:606)
09-16 19:00:22.708: W/System.err(32274):    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:584)
09-16 19:00:22.708: W/System.err(32274):    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:543)
09-16 19:00:22.718: W/System.err(32274):    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:521)
09-16 19:00:22.718: W/System.err(32274):    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:426)
09-16 19:00:22.718: W/System.err(32274):    at com.honeydewit.XMLMarshaller.generateListFromXml(XMLMarshaller.java:37)
09-16 19:00:22.718: W/System.err(32274):    at com.honeydewit.AttachmentProcessor.onCreate(AttachmentProcessor.java:46)
09-16 19:00:22.718: W/System.err(32274):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
09-16 19:00:22.718: W/System.err(32274):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
09-16 19:00:22.718: W/System.err(32274):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
09-16 19:00:22.718: W/System.err(32274):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
09-16 19:00:22.718: W/System.err(32274):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
09-16 19:00:22.728: W/System.err(32274):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
09-16 19:00:22.728: W/System.err(32274):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-16 19:00:22.728: W/System.err(32274):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-16 19:00:22.728: W/System.err(32274):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
09-16 19:00:22.728: W/System.err(32274):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-16 19:00:22.728: W/System.err(32274):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-16 19:00:22.738: W/System.err(32274):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
09-16 19:00:22.738: W/System.err(32274):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
09-16 19:00:22.738: W/System.err(32274):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The JVM Classloader can't find the class `com.j256.ormlite.dao.LazyForeignCollection` - are you sure it's available in your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I needed to manually set the class loader in the XMLMarshaller class.

[Android: "Class loader may fail for processes that host multiple applications"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407006/android-class-loader-may-fail-for-processes-that-host-multiple-applications)