# Google Plus Domain API Android Exception

Tags: java, android, google-plus-domains

I am trying to get Circles of user using Google Plus Domain API Android.

I imported following libraries first in my project:

```
google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-api-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-oauth-client-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-http-client-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-http-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar
gson-2.1.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar
jackson-core-2.1.3.jar
jsr305-1.3.9.jar
protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar
```

Please find the [link](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup) for more info.

I did the following steps:

1. Get authentication token:

   ```
   String accountName = params[0];
   String GPLUS_PROFILE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile";
   String GPLUS_LOGIN = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login";
   String GPLUS_CIRCLES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read";
   String GPLUS_ME = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me";
   String scopes = "oauth2:" + GPLUS_PROFILE + " " + GPLUS_LOGIN + " "
           + GPLUS_CIRCLES + " " + GPLUS_ME;
   String token = null;
   try {
       token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(LoginActivity.this,
               accountName, scopes);
       return token;
   } catch (IOException e) {
       Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
   } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
       startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQ_SIGN_IN_REQUIRED);
       return null;
   } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
       Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
   }
   ```
2. Now as I received an authentication token, I tried to create PlusDomain Class Object to get details about user:

   ```
   public void getPlusDomain(String response) {
       HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
       JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

       GoogleCredential googleCredential = new GoogleCredential()
               .setAccessToken(response);
       plusDomains = new PlusDomains.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory,
               googleCredential).setApplicationName("Google  Mini")
               .build();
       Person mePerson;
       try {
           mePerson = plusDomains.people().get("me").execute();
           System.out.println("ID:\t" + mePerson.getId());
           System.out.println("Display Name:\t" + mePerson.getDisplayName());
           System.out.println("Image URL:\t" + mePerson.getImage().getUrl());
           System.out.println("Profile URL:\t" + mePerson.getUrl());
       } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```

I get the following exception:

[image: Exception]

I used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407006/android-class-loader-may-fail-for-processes-that-host-multiple-applications) to Solve the problem and the exception goes

```
 JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(
                jsonFactory.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

however after that i get

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException
```

How to solve this issue and why this exception coming

[image]